# Choosing $x$ to prove a function is discontinuous

Tags: epsilon-delta

I am trying to show, using the epsilon-delta definition of the limit, that the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $x = 0$}\\x & \text{if $x \neq 0$}\end{cases}$$
is discontinuous at $x = 0$.

We want to show that
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0\;\forall \delta > 0\;\exists x\;(|x| < \delta \wedge |x-1| \geq \varepsilon).$$
I started by trying to choose a suitable $x$ in terms of $\delta$, but $|x-1| \geq \varepsilon > 0$ implies that $x \neq 1$. I am finding it hard to find an expression in terms of $\delta$ that never equals 1.

Comment: You need choosea specific number c and then negate the definition of "f(x) is continuous at c". Hint: try to do that for c=0. What you have written will not prove f(x) discontinuous.

Comment: @coffeemath $c=0$ was already chosen and the negation of continuity already written, except that the condition $x\ne0$ (or $0<|x|$) was forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in(0,1/2]$ (you forgot the condition $x\ne0$ in what "we want to show"), $$|x-1|=1-x\ge1/2$$ hence we may choose $\varepsilon=1/2$ and then, for any $\delta>0$, pick any $x\in(0,\min(1/2,\delta))$.